# How to execute Redis commands remotely

Tags: redis, ibm-cloud

I have a redis resource in IBM Cloud(IBM Cloud Databases for Redis). I want to execute the redis commands such as 'config set notify-keyspace-events $KExe' in a remote session.

I use the below command to connect to connect to the redis instance through redli.

```
ibmcloud login --apikey <api key> -a https://cloud.ibm.com -g <resource group name> -r <region>
ibmcloud cdb deployment-connections <ibm redis instance name> -s --user admin --password <password>
```

I am able to connect with the redis instance, and it give the output as 
'Connected to 4.0.10'. I can, then, execute the redis commands and type 'exit' to exit out of the redis session.
How can I automate this part of execution of redis commands, get those executed remotely, and then exit out of the redis session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with redis, but I believe the following will work (at least it appeared to work for me)

```
ibmcloud cdb deployment-connections redisdeleteme -s --user admin --password PASSWORD << 'EOF'
config set notify-keyspace-events $KExe
config get notify-keyspace-events
EOF
```

When executed it looked like this:

```
~ $ ibmcloud cdb deployment-connections redisdeleteme -s --user admin --password PASSWORD << 'EOF'
> config set notify-keyspace-events $KExe
> config get notify-keyspace-events
> EOF
Connected to 4.0.10
OK
 1) "notify-keyspace-events"
 2) "$xeKE"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute Redis commands from Bash command line:

```
./redis-cli -h XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -p YYYY HMSET 'users' 'joe' '12345' 'maria' 'qwerty' 'sim' '1970-01-01'
```

It is what are you searching for?

And you can create a file with your commands and execute them as:

```
./redis-cli -h XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -p YYYY < commandsfile.txt
```

Comment: suppose i have two commands, 'command 1 ' to connect to redis instance, and 'command 2' to execute it in the redis instance session without interacting with it.

When i execute 'command 1', it open an interactive session. How to execute 'command 2' in that interactive session and than exit out of it remotely.

Comment: Why do you want to execute `command2` in interactive section? You can execute both commands (and more) in the same one-line command. I have updated my answer.

Comment: thank you very much. Your answer served my purpose. I was able to run the redis commands this way.